# Инкремент аргумента функции

Tags: c#, массивы

```
public class TestClass{
    public static void main(String args[ ] ){
      int i = 1;
      int[] iArr = {1};
      incr(i) ;
      incr(iArr) ;
      System.out.println( "i = " + i + "  iArr[0] = " + iArr [ 0 ] ) ;
    }

    public static void incr(int   n ) { n++ ; }
    public static void incr(int[ ] n ) { n [ 0 ]++ ; }
}
```

Почему функция `incr` не увеличивает `i` на единицу?

Comment: потому что аргумент по значению передается

Comment: Я бы немного уточнил... Потому что тип передаваемого аргумента не ссылочный и следовательно он передаётся не по ссылке, а по значению. Если Вы хотите изменять значение не ссылочного типа, то передавайте его по ссылке: `void incr(ref int n){ n++; }` И не забывайте при вызове метода явно указывать `ref` так: `incr(ref i);`